# Calendar.getInstance() returns 1-2-5(Day-Month-Year)

Tags: android, calendar, android-calendar

I have this chunk of code:

```
Calendar date1 = Calendar.getInstance();      
DateTime dateTime1 = new DateTime(date1.YEAR, date1.MONTH, date1.DAY_OF_MONTH, date1.HOUR_OF_DAY, date1.MINUTE, date1.SECOND);
```

My problem is that `date1` returns the date 01/02/0005 (in a 1/2/5 format). I read about SimpleDateFormat, however it returns the same value.

Comment: Once check with your device date.

Comment: 15/03/2016, I'm using my android device to test my app.

Comment: obviously because you are using constant instead date parts ... I bet(without checking the source) that Calendar.YEAR == 5, Calendar.MONTH == 2 ...

Comment: Sorry, I got it, what you need to do is `date1.get(Calendar.YEAR), date1.get(Calendar.MONTH), date1.get(Calendar.DATE)` respectively to get the year,month and date from the calendar object.

Comment: @AntónioPaulo Much simpler solution: if `DateTime` is the one from joda lib .... `DateTime dateTime1 = DateTime.now();` <= this is equivalent of your code ...

Comment: Selvin, the `DateTime()` do the same as `DateTime.now()` but thanks for the tip. I had another question and i've posted it after this one and there was a answer that said not to use Calendar and DateTime together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`date1.YEAR` returns only a *constant* value. The same value as `Calendar.YEAR`.

Instead, you need to use the `date1.get(...)` method, in conjunction with `Calendar.YEAR`. See this example:

```
  Calendar date1 = Calendar.getInstance();      
  DateTime dateTime1 = new DateTime(date1.get(Calendar.YEAR), date1.get(Calendar.MONTH), date1.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH), date1.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY), date1.get(Calendar.MINUTE), date1.get(Calendar.SECOND);
```

Comment: Your answer is almost the same as Vickyexpert, but you explain why.

Answer (score 1):

Try these lines of code to get the correct date:-

```
Calendar ci = Calendar.getInstance();
     String AM_PM;

      if(ci.get(Calendar.AM_PM)==0)
        {
             AM_PM ="AM";
        }
        else
        {
             AM_PM ="PM";
        }
        String CiDateTime = "" + ci.get(Calendar.YEAR) + "-" + 
            (ci.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1) + "-" +
            ci.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)+" "+AM_PM;

         System.out.println("time=========================================="+CiDateTime);
```

For yours solution, try these

```
  Calendar ci = Calendar.getInstance();
  DateTime dateTime1 = new DateTime(ci.get(Calendar.YEAR), ci.get(Calendar.MONTH), ci.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH), ci.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY), ci.get(Calendar.MINUTE), ci.get(Calendar.SECOND);
```

Comment: It returns the correct value but when I try to use it, like date1.YEAR, it return the values that I mentioned on the question.

Comment: Its wrong to get the correct date or time therefore i have suggested my answer

Answer (score -1):

Try below code:

```
Calendar date1 = Calendar.getInstance();   
Date date = new Date(); 
date1.setTime(date);   
DateTime dateTime1 = new DateTime(date1.YEAR, date1.MONTH, date1.DAY_OF_MONTH, date1.HOUR_OF_DAY, date1.MINUTE, date1.SECOND);
```